# Why this failure for hypersetup using an input or usepackage approach?

Tags: hyperref, hyperxmp

I am working to develop a template as a class file (expanding from the memoir class). The development includes a set of empty `\newcommand` invocations that are to be changed depending on where the template is used. I also want to carry certain settings into the PDF document appropriately, such as author, title, and keywords. I am using `\hyperxmp` and `\hyperref`. Finally, to reduce clutter in the main template class file, I put the `\hypersetup` command into a separate style file, call that style file with `\usepackage`, and use a `\AtBeginDocument` directive to invoke `\hypersetup{...}`.

The overall format is therefore as below.

```
\documentclass{mytemplate}
\renewcommand*{\theCourse}{My Course}
\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

where `mytemplate.cls` appears as below

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{mytemplate}[...]
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{memoir}}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{memoir}
%% ... other packages
\RequirePackage{hyperxmp}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
%% ... load settings
\newcommand*{\theCourse}{}
\RequirePackage{mytemplatesettings}
```

and `mytemplatesettings.sty` has a part that appears as below

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{%
        pdftitle=\theCourse{},
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue
        }
    }
```

### --> The Problem

The problem with the above approach is that the `colorlinks` and `linkcolor` directives are ignored. To overcome this, I have to use this line in the class

```
\RequirePackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

and remove the corresponding settings in the `mytemplatesettings.sty`.

I can reproduce the behavior with the MWE below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\theCourse}{The Course}

%% FAILURE
%% compile once then uncomment next line
%% and comment out the \hypersetup section
%\input{hypersets}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=blue,
    pdftitle=\theCourse{}
    }

\begin{filecontents}{hypersets.tex}
\AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        pdftitle=\theCourse{}
        }
    }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\vfill

This is for \theCourse{}.

\section{The First}

\lipsum[1]

\section{The Second}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Where is the mistake in believing that I should be able to put the `colorlinks` directive into an external package (or input) file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current hyperref version disables `colorlinks` at begin document, so your setting is too late.

With a current latex you can set a rule to ensure that your settings are before the hyperref code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperxmp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand*{\theCourse}{The Course}


\begin{filecontents}{hypersets.tex}
\AtBeginDocument[hypersets]{%
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks=true,
        linkcolor=blue,
        pdftitle=\theCourse{}
        }
    }
\DeclareHookRule{begindocument}{hypersets}{before}{hyperref}
    
\end{filecontents}

\input{hypersets}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents{}

\vfill

This is for \theCourse{}.

\section{The First}

\lipsum[1]

\section{The Second}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

In a future hyperref this will not be needed as colorlinks can then be set in the document too. You can test this future version by starting your document with

```
\RequirePackage{pdfmanagement-testphase}
\DeclareDocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass{article}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and clarification. This works as you have documented. In the meantime, since the development is solely for me, I am foregoing the `\AtBeginDocument` approach and using a `\setHyperref` command that I invoke just before `\begin{document}`. I've also moved the `colorlinks` and `linkcolor` settings as options to the `\RequirePackage[..]{hyperref}` in the class itself, since these settings are truly "static" over all cases of the study guide.